# Data being overwritten with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a problem with a VBA for excel. I use this macro to go into other stored excel workbooks, scan all the worksheets for dates on when a certain class starts a certain area. Then it will compile all the infromation into one worksheet and sort by starting date. After I expanded the items it was looking for, I hit the size limit and had to break it into two subs. Now the promblem is that the first sub runs fine but when the second one runs it overwrite the data in the first sub. I tried to insert the following with errors.

```
iRow = Ws.Cells(Ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

I am able to get the code to run now by adding the following

```
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Board")
```

I have placed this code in the main and sub portions of the Macro. The problem continues where I get my first sub overwritten by the other. Any help or ideas would be great.

Thank you

**EDIT**

Code from comments:

```
Set appExcel = Nothing
intcounter = intcounter + 1
strClassList = Right(strClassList, Len(strClassList) - 2)
strClassDateList = Right(strClassDateList, Len(strClassDateList) - 2)
strClassHourList = Right(strClassHourList, Len(strClassHourList) - 2)
strClassStopList = Right(strClassStopList, Len(strClassStopList) - 2)
intMainCounterTop = (intMainCounter + (Len(strClassList) - Len(Replace(strClassList, Chr(13), "", 1, , vbBinaryCompare)))) '- 1

For i = 2 To intMainCounterTop
    Worksheets("Board").Cells(i, 1) = "15U3 " & Left(strClassList, InStr(1, strClassList, Chr(13), vbBinaryCompare) - 1)
    Worksheets("Board").Cells(i, 2) = "AF"
    Worksheets("Board").Cells(i, 3) = Left(strClassDateList, InStr(1, strClassDateList, Chr(13), vbBinaryCompare) - 1)
    Worksheets("Board").Cells(i, 4) = Left(strClassHourList, InStr(1, strClassHourList, Chr(13), vbBinaryCompare) - 1)
    Worksheets("Board").Cells(i, 5) = Left(strClassStopList, InStr(1, strClassStopList, Chr(13), vbBinaryCompare) - 1)

    strClassList = Right(strClassList, Len(strClassList) - InStr(1, strClassList, Chr(13), vbBinaryCompare) - 1)
    strClassDateList = Right(strClassDateList, Len(strClassDateList) - InStr(1, strClassDateList, Chr(13), vbBinaryCompare) - 1)
    strClassHourList = Right(strClassHourList, Len(strClassHourList) - InStr(1, strClassHourList, Chr(13), vbBinaryCompare) - 1)
    strClassStopList = Right(strClassStopList, Len(strClassStopList) - InStr(1, strClassStopList, Chr(13), vbBinaryCompare) - 1)
Next i

Worksheets("Board").Cells(i, 1) = "15U3 " & strClassList
Worksheets("Board").Cells(i, 2) = "AF"
Worksheets("Board").Cells(i, 3) = strClassDateList
Worksheets("Board").Cells(i, 4) = strClassHourList
Worksheets("Board").Cells(i, 5) = strClassStopList
```

Comment: What are you doing with `iRow`, we will need to see more code in order to be able to help?

Comment: I am just trying to get the second sub to add its results to the same worksheet that the first sub filled in. Right now they are overwriting each other. I have something like 3200 lines of code. What part do you need to see? I can post some snippets of it.

Comment: can you show the code you use to paste the values?

Comment: This will be in 4 parts.

Comment: @GustaveJones Please don't add that code to comments. Edit your question to include it.

Comment: Not addressing your specific problem in this case, but you have a lot of repeated code in there which you would benefit a lot from refactoring into standalone Sub's or Function's.  That will ease any maintenance by making your code a lot easier to manage.

Comment: I am new to this and trying to figure this out as I go. Any advice and help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I don't see anything (from the code in your question) that would overwrite the data. Are you sure it isn't happening at a different point in your code? Have you tried stepping through your code (`F8` while in break mode) to see when it happens?

Comment: I have tried stepping and I can not find it either. Where would be the best location to place the iRow statement?

Comment: Not sure if I can do this, but here is a link to another site with the entire code.http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/754791-adding-data-exisitng-data-error.html

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but a pointer to how you can improve your code a little.

It seems from the code you posted that you have a number of strings which are really lists of items separated by `Chr(13)`, which you're working through to extract the individual pieces.

If this is actually what you're doing, then it would be much less code (and easier to manage) if you first use

```
arrStrings = Split(bigStringHere, Chr(13))
```

to convert each of your strings to arrays.  You can then loop through these arrays with much less coding overhead.

Example:

```
Sub StringsToArray()

    Dim strClasses, arrClasses, n

    strClasses = "Class1" & Chr(13) & "Class2" & Chr(13) & "Class3"

    arrClasses = Split(strClasses, Chr(13))
    'arrClasses is now an array containing all the
    '  items from "strClasses" which were separated by Chr(13)
    '  You can use a counter to loop through the array
    For n = LBound(arrClasses) To UBound(arrClasses)
        Debug.Print n, arrClasses(n)
    Next n

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I am working with someone else's project and I am trying to updated and clean it up. This really is my first VBA project and I am on a steep learning curve. Any help is always welcome.